# objective c how to get placemarks of given coordinates

Tags: objective-c, ios, reverse-geocoding

I have a question related to reverse geo-coding.

In my app, I have some coordinates (not my current coordinates) and I want to convert them into placemarks. I've dug a lot of websites and codes but they are all about reverse geocoding of current location...

Is there any way to get placemarks of specified coordinates (which are not current location)?

And if there is, please help me with some code or references.

Comment: What do you mean? You will have to do the same thing whether the location is yours or not. Here is some reference if you're developing for iOS 5: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class

Comment: You cannot assign location to CLLocation.coordinat.longitude or latitude. and reverseGeoCoding method accepts only CLLocation not CLLocationCoordinate2D

Comment: `CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways:-

First way:-
Get the info using google api

```
-(void)findAddresstoCorrespondinglocation
{
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&sensor=false",myCoordInfo.latitude,myCoordInfo.longitude];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(mapAddressResponse:)];
    [request setDidFailSelector: @selector(mapAddressResponseFailed:)];
    [networkQueue addOperation: request];
    [networkQueue go];

}
```

in response you will get all information about the location coordinates you specified.

Second Approach:-

Implement reverse geocoding

a.)add `mapkit` framework

b.)Make instance of `MKReverseGeocoder` in .h file

```
MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder;
```

c.)in .m file

```
self.reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:cordInfo];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
```

Implement two delegate methods of `MKReverseGeoCoder`

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"MKReverseGeocoder has failed.");
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    MKPlacemark * myPlacemark = placemark;
    NSString *city = myPlacemark.thoroughfare;
    NSString *subThrough=myPlacemark.subThoroughfare;
    NSString *locality=myPlacemark.locality;
    NSString *subLocality=myPlacemark.subLocality;
    NSString *adminisArea=myPlacemark.administrativeArea;
    NSString *subAdminArea=myPlacemark.subAdministrativeArea;
    NSString *postalCode=myPlacemark.postalCode;
    NSString *country=myPlacemark.country;
    NSString *countryCode=myPlacemark.countryCode;
    NSLog(@"city%@",city);
    NSLog(@"subThrough%@",subThrough);
    NSLog(@"locality%@",locality);
    NSLog(@"subLocality%@",subLocality);
    NSLog(@"adminisArea%@",adminisArea);
    NSLog(@"subAdminArea%@",subAdminArea);
    NSLog(@"postalCode%@",postalCode);
    NSLog(@"country%@",country);
    NSLog(@"countryCode%@",countryCode);

    }
```

Comment: just to note: in iOS 5.0, it is deprecated in favor of `GLGeocoder` class: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder

Comment: I would suggest to use google api method .It is easy and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks Gypsa  I will try the first approach but as I know MKReverseGeoCoder is depricated in iOS 5. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dear Gypsa!

I've tried to implement this code(first approach). But as I haven't deal with ASIHTTPRequest I couldn't understand which type should have networkQueue. 
[networkQueue addOperation: request];
[networkQueue go];
And also could you clarify which part brings me response. Does it should be the mapAddressResponse: method.???

Comment: I found Simple way to do  CLLocation *aLoc=[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitudeCL longitude:longitudeCL];

Comment: Great to know that your problem solved.for ASIHTTPRequest go through this link:-http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/