# Get User Location in appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation, appdelegate

Heres the scenario. I have two UIViewControllers. Lets say, `PresentinLondonViewController` and `NotPresentinLondonViewController`. The view that i want to load first should depend on the current user. Lets say if and only if the current users location is London, then i want  PresentViewController to show up otherwise NotPresentViewController.

I ve done a lot of research, couldn't find anything concrete even tried my hand on protocol. Doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CLLocationManager` to get your current position , and after that you can do `reverse geocoding` to get the address from the coordinates.

In that address, if it's accurate you'll find the word '`London`' to match your needs.

Do this in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` :

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
manager.delegate = self;
//Here you set the Distance Filter that you need
manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
// Here you set the Accuracy 
  manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
```

And in the delegate function:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{


        CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
        [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            //Picked the first placemark
             CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
           //you can play and see how to grab the key name that you want.
             NSLog(@"Address %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",placemark.thoroughfare,addressNumber]);
          //Do your additional setup here

        }];
        [geocoder release];
        [location release];

}
```

And if you want to delay the loading so you can get the time to grab all of the info then you can present another `viewcontroller` which has the `splash screen` on it and do the checking there/or in the `appDelegate`.

Comment: Thank @soryngod!! I had figured that out.. well though i have successfully managed to implement `CLLocationManager`+`CoreLocation` within my View Controllers previously. I some how am not able to do so in appDelegate. I tried to setting the location manager in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but it appears the the code after `[ locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` gets executed and root view controller is shown rather than the control being passed onto `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations`

Comment: The problem there is that you need to delay the loading of the application so you could do this setup behind the scene, you can present another viewcontroller with the splash screen and then when your are asked to give your location ,if the user presses cancel then you present the NotPresentInLondon controller , else you check to see if you find London and decide which viewcontroller to use.

Comment: Hmmm.. Another stupid question. Though I know how ill manage it if i were to add an addition splash screen. is there a way to make the app delegate not load the root view controller until the setup is completed??

Comment: better to do it like this. load the splashviewcontroller  and you could remove the rootviewcontroller and have a black screen but don't think that will be so good for you.

Comment: Sweet!! Don't worry about the black screen. Ill find a way to negate that :) Could you add your view on adding the splash screen as an answer so that i can mark it as correct. Thanks much!! Cheers

Comment: Hey bro it worked out quite well.. in my splash screen i update the user location and then compare the fetched city name with london.. depending on the result i set the rootviewcontroller of navigation controller.. well black screen was simply negating by adding self.view.backgroundcolor :) Cheers and once again Thanks a ton

Comment: Yeeess, glad that I could help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `MKReverseGeocoder` to get [MKPlacemark](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPlacemark_Class/Reference/Reference.html) , you can get apple sample code of [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009469)

or here is another link

[objective c how to get placemarks of given coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031373/objective-c-how-to-get-placemarks-of-given-coordinates)

Comment: thanks @Rajneesh071. Im sorry if the question title is misleading. but my concern is more about setting the root view controller depending upon the user location.. p.s i know how to get the current user location

Answer (score 0):

get current latLong from `CLLocationManager` for that you have to use

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
//for iOS 6+
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
//for lower then iOS 6
}
```

for getting address from your lat and long use this url

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&latlng=%f,%f",YourLatitude,YourLongitude];
```

Comment: thanks @Nirav. Im sorry if the question title is misleading. but my concern is more about setting the root view controller depending upon the user location.. p.s i know how to get the current user location